# Сan I use IOMMU for VT-d to give each virtual machine one at a time GPU?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, x86, graphics-processing-unit

If I use VMWare with 4 virtual-machines and 4 GPUs (nVidia Quadro/Tesla), then can I give (move) some devices to different virtual-machines for each by a single card?

If I have one of these CPU, then I have IOMMU: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOMMU-supporting_hardware#CPUs

> Peripheral memory paging can be supported by an **IOMMU**.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU#Advantages

I.e. if I have IOMMU, then I have [Intel's "Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O" (VT-d)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29) which make able to do what I want.

But when we use nVidia GPU with CUDA >= 5.0, we can use RDMA GPUDirect, and know that:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#how-gpudirect-rdma-works

> Traditionally, resources like BAR windows are mapped to user or kernel
>   address space using the CPU's MMU as memory mapped I/O (MMIO)
>   addresses. However, because **current operating systems don't have
>   sufficient mechanisms for exchanging MMIO regions between drivers**, the
>   NVIDIA kernel driver exports functions to perform the necessary
>   address translations and mappings.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#supported-systems

> **RDMA for GPUDirect currently relies upon all physical addresses**
>   being the same from the PCI devices' point of view. This makes it
>   incompatible with IOMMUs and hence they must be disabled for RDMA for
>   GPUDirect to work.

Why nVidia recomended to disable IOMMU, and can I use IOMMU on Sandy/Ivy-Bridge for VT-d to give each virtual machine one at a time GPU?